# Different types of continuity in $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Consider the following functional $J$ on $\ell^2$ which for $x = \{x_n\}$ is defined by
$$J(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{1/n}x_{n}^{2}.$$

- Is $J$ continuous?
- Is $J$ lower semi-continuous?
- Is $J$ weakly continuous?

Comment: It seems to me that $J(x) \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: what have you done ?

Comment: You have $x$ and $x_n$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $J$ is the composition of two maps
$$
\varphi: \ell^2 \to \ell^1 \text{ given by} (x_n) \mapsto (x_n^2)
$$
and
$$
L: \ell^1 \to \mathbb{C} \text{ given by } (x_n) \mapsto \sum n^{1/n} x_n
$$
Now check that $\varphi$ is continuous, and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1
$$
and so $\exists M > 0$ such that $n^{1/n} \leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, if $\|x\|_1 \leq 1$, then
$$
|L(x)| \leq M\|x\|_1 \leq M
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \sup_{\|x\|_1 \leq 1} |L(x)| < \infty
$$
So $L$ is continuous; which implies that $J$ is continuous.

Comment: I thought of considering the bilinear form $B(x,y) = \sum n^{1/n}x_ny_n$, but that works too.

Comment: Thanks for your earlier comment. I wasn't thinking when I wrote my earlier answer!